# java for each: using method in the list part (right hand side of :)

Tags: java, foreach

I know it's a stupid question, since I've never seen any example that using method returns list in the for each loop, I intuitively feel that is not a good idea:

```
for (String element : computeElementList()) {
    Systems.out.print(element);
}
```

should I first assign the method to a variable? Or is this not necessary at all, because this computeElementList() method will just be called one time at the beginning of the loop?

Comment: You can add a print statement to check behavior instead of posting here

Comment: wow, so many negatives. It seems I only have myself to blame. Anyway good to know that the stackoverflow still alive and the users become stricter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra variable is not necessary because `computeElementList()` will just be called just once at the beginning of the loop.

Unless you need to the result of `computeElementList()` for something else, creating a new variable would just add clutter to the code (IMO).

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really increasing the readability.  Since the function returns something that you can iterate over:  Collection, array, etc .  It won't matter.  The same is true of functions that return booleans and are written so:

```
if(doSomething())  {...}
```

The function will only be called once.  If it wasn't you would permgen / run out of memory pretty quickly even on a list of size 1.