# Is it possible for right side of for each expression to get recalculated on every loop?

Tags: java, performance, foreach

I was told by a coworker of mine that it's better `performance` to declare a variable outside of a `foreach` and use that instead of putting inside the `foreach` expression.

So instead of this:

```
for (Foo foo : otherFoo.getFoos()) {
    ....
}
```

it would be better `performance` to capture those foos in a variable and use that instead:

```
List<Foo> foos = otherFoo.getFoos();
for (Foo foo : foos) {
    ....
}
```

Is there any truth to this? Is it possible that putting a method call on the right side of a `foreach` could impact `performance` negatively?

Comment: hmmm - maybe already answered...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923011/java-for-each-using-method-in-the-list-part-right-hand-side-of

Comment: I won't imagine what happens if the right side would be recalculated each time and returns different results.